# Redirect after a new node is added but not edited

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have a custom redirect on node submit.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_node_submit';
}

function custom_node_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'request-sent';
}
```

However, I would like to redirect only when a new node is created but not updated.
How do I check the action being executed on the node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_node_submit';
}

function custom_node_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if (arg(2) != "edit") {
      $form_state['redirect'] = 'request-sent';
    }
}
```

Comment: $form['#node']->is_new = TRUE for new nodes FYI.